# rails - Searching across two combined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my rails app, my User column has a fname and lname columns. I want to allow for searching for a user that does either fname, lname, or combined.

I tried:

```
  @users = User.find( :all,
                      :select => 'users.*',
                      :conditions => ["fname || ' ' || lname ILIKE ?", "Lenny"]
                    )
```

But that isn't yields results. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@users = User.find( :all,
                      :select => 'users.*',
                      :conditions => ["fname || ' ' || lname LIKE ?", '%'+"Lenny"+'%']
                    )
```

Thanks.....

Comment: That works great, thanks. Any ideas on what kind of index I should have to make this run smoothly?